# Css doesnt work with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

im working with Spring Framework and Thymeleaf. I put to my project validation.properties. When I used method which has connect with validation.properties always I got errors so i found method which resolve it.

Exactly this one

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // Load file: validation.properties
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validation");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

but now my css file doesnt work with that solution. How can i resolve it? My css path is /resources/static/main.css.

Validation.properties has path /resources/validation.properties.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so remove `@EnableWebMvc` as it disables auto-config.

Comment: Working. So that was pretty simple to resolve it :d Thanks you